# Xcode does not autocomplete for OSX code

Tags: xcode, macos, sprite-kit

It is OK for Xcode autocompletion when I write iOS codes. But if I wrote something like

```
#if os(OSX)
    return [
        NSApplicationWillResignActiveNotification,
        NSWindowDidMiniaturizeNotification
    ]
```

Xcode would not autocomplete the constant from AppKit, and there is no syntax color either. Please help.

Comment: is this code that builds for both iOS & MacOS?  Xcode projects typically only autocomplete from one SDK (iOS or MacOS) at one time..

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Yes, it builds for both. Now I have to go through the document for OSX APIs every time without autocompletion...